# Find all duplicate values in one column and combine all its values

Tags: excel, duplicates, unique-values

So I got this excel file with a lot of data which is why I want to avoid doing all this manually. Basically what I want to do is find all values that is the same in one column and then combine all it's values to one row.

If I have this data in a worksheet.

[image]

I would like the output to be like this

[image]

I appreciate all the help I can get.

**EDIT:**

This is what I get from a Pivot Table

[image]

When I actually would want it to look like this.

[image]

Answer (score -1):

You must use Pivot Table function from (i recommend it) MS Excel.

It lets you to set wich columns becomes rows, what type of values they will contain and much more.

Pivot Tables are what you want.

> It saved my career at my previous job :)

Here you got some screenshot of example for making sums for all duplicates in first column:
[image: After pivot]

original table:
[image: Before pivot]

Comment: I tried that but it gets all messed up.. For some reason all the values get mashed together in one column and the values just show counts of how many times the value appears and not the actual value.

Comment: Edited answer for you.

Comment: That's the thing. I don't want the sum or the product or any mathematical operation. All I want to do is display the value as it is since most of the data contains of strings

Comment: Ah ok then. Look at my first screen shot. Instead of putting all that columns into VALUES field try to put them one by one into ROWS field. Try mixing it a bit in order in rows field and u will find sollution you want :)

Comment: I tried that as well and at least it's better but still not what I'm looking for. If you look at the last screenshot that is the result I get from putting the columns into ROWS. I would like all the values to be printed out in separates cells along the row of the ORDER it belongs to.